# Why can't I use relativeLayout as the parentView?

Tags: android, android-layout, crash

This is what I have for `setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);` and I don't understand why every time I run my app it crashes.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
   xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:id="@+id/Mainbody"
   android:layout_width= "wrap_content"
android:layout_height= "wrap_content" 
    >
<LinearLayout
android:id="@+id/Boss"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="horizontal">


</LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

But if I use `<LinearLayou>` as the main parent instead, it won't crashes!

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
   xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:id="@+id/Mainbody"
   android:layout_width= "wrap_content"
android:layout_height= "wrap_content" 
    >
<LinearLayout
android:id="@+id/Boss"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="horizontal">


</LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

and here is what log cat has to say about it..

```
05-20 11:55:14.400: E/AndroidRuntime(2052): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-20 11:55:14.400: E/AndroidRuntime(2052): java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.LinearLayout$LayoutParams cannot be cast to android.widget.RelativeLayout$LayoutParams
```

I don't really get it..

Comment: can you post your logcat output when you use relative layout

Comment: crash => post stacktrace

Comment: trivially, you are casting your view to a LinearLayout somewhere.

Comment: Thanks I have checked my log cat and posted the logs but I still can't understand why it crashes

Comment: @love you should post the full log-trace (all red lines) and please post `onCreate()` method of your `Activity`

Comment: Assuming you are using eclipse: sometimes it doesn't auto-build correctly when layouts types are changed in the xml, try cleaning and re-building. Also verify that you are not calling `findViewById(R.id.Mainbody)` and casting it to the wrong layout type in your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is not in your xml, its in the java file. You are doing something like this

```
LinearLayout xyz = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.Mainbody)
```

while using `RelativeLayout`. So you are getting `ClassCastException`. Do it like this

```
 RelativeLayout xyz = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.Mainbody)
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. But I didn't do that in my java file.

Comment: Then try cleaning your project and then run it.